# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on a domain forwarding to another

Tags: ssl, url, dns, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have worked on two domains `*.es` and `*.com` which the `.es` had installed the SSL certificate whilst I was waiting for the `.com` to migrate to the new domain provider.

When the `.com` arrived, I have used it as the main domain and pointed the `.es` domain to it. I have also moved the **SSL certificate** from the `.es` to the `.com`.

Browsing the www.*.es is correctly forwarding to the www.*.com site.

However, the browser still suggests **https:**//www.*.es. throwing the **ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**.

It's solved clearing the cache **but** my client's customers do not necessarily know they have to clear the browser cache to stop it suggesting the already visited **https** site.

How can it be solved?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: For reference of the error: https://www.marbelwear.es

Comment: You question is a bit unclear but I assume that you had a 301 redirect before and now are affected by the problem that the client still have this **permanent** redirect cached rightfully.